# Varnish no cache for my web site

Tags: linux, security, caching, varnish

this my configuration

```
backend axelaris {
  .host = "www.axelaris-hosting.com";
  .port = "http";
}

sub vcl_recv {
   if (req.http.host ~ "^(www.)?axelaris-hosting.com$") {
       set req.backend = axelaris;
   }
}
```

but when i tape
varnishtop -i rxurl

allways i have list length 0

help please to cache my web site
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

If rxurl gives an empty list it means that you're not getting any request coming into varnish. The reason for this seems to be that you are trying to make both your web server and varnish to listen on the same port. If you have varnish and the web server (for instance apache) on the same server you need to make varnish listen on port 80 and the web server listen on another port (for instance 8080). And then set .port for that backend appropriately of course.

Comment: thanks for your answer i canhe the port of apache to 8080 but i have the same result  Best regards